# Authorization roles not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

Here's my Sign Up and Login action methods in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignUp(User _user)
    {
        _user.Authorize = CustomRoles.RegisteredUser;
        int lastuserid = entities.Users.Last().UserID;
        _user.UserID = lastuserid + 1;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(_user.UserName, CustomRoles.RegisteredUser);
            entities.Users.Add(_user);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(_user);
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        LoginViewModel LVM = new LoginViewModel();
        HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserName"];
        if (existingCookie != null)
        {
            LVM.UserName = existingCookie.Value;
        }

        return View(LVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (u.RememberMe==true)
            {
                HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserName"];
                if (existingCookie != null)
                {

                    existingCookie.Value = u.UserName;
                    existingCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-20);
                }


                HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", u.UserName);
                newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
                Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
            }
            var v = entities.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = u.UserName;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

and here's a sample of the action methods they're supposed to go to, some of them are in a different controller but the outcome is the same for all of them:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.RegisteredUser)]
    public ActionResult Orders(User U)
    {

        return View();
    }

[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.Manager)]
    public ActionResult Stock()
    {

        return View(entities.Cars.ToList());
    }
```

what happens is i get redirected back to the Login method, which is what should be happening if a user isn't logged in, but a user is logged in and it's still hapening

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement Form Authorization, but as i think you forgot about authorize attribute use HttpContext.User.IsInRole method to detect is user can access to action. To resolve your problem you can configure forms auth via your web.config or you manually assign your HttpContext.User via HttpModule or with application events in Global.asax.cs like this for example:

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserName"];            
        if (existingCookie != null) {
             context = new  new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(existingCookie.Value), new string[]{"Admin", "Manager"});
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How can i configure forms authentication via the web.config?